# Does FIXME: NYI in MutableCallSite.syncAll mean not yet implemented?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, jvm

In `java.lang.invoke` there are two interesting constructs, `MutableCallSite` and `SwitchPoint`. They are described as offering a way to change their targets (to an arbitrary different target for a `MutableCallSite`, or to a predefined when-invalidated target for a `SwitchPoint`), with other threads guaranteed to pick up the update, but with reduced overhead for the uses of the MCS or SP when it hasn't been changed (reduced, compared to a check with synchronization effects on every use). The `SwitchPoint` documentation says it can be built over `MutableCallSite`, and in the OpenJDK sources on GitHub, it is. So the place to look for the magic is in `MutableCallSite.syncAll`.

In [the source for that method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/invoke/MutableCallSite.java#L281), the magic seems to have three steps:

- Step 1 is a `lazySet` (JMM effects of `setRelease`) on a private `AtomicInteger` that no other thread will ever read;
- Step 2 looks at all of the passed `MutableCallSite` references to confirm none are null;
- Step 3 is a comment: `// FIXME: NYI`

To an untrained eye, there seems to be real work left for that comment to do. ;)

It seems like the developers of Android saw that comment and [removed the method from Android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/17162a1%5E!/ojluni/src/main/java/java/lang/invoke/MutableCallSite.java) because they didn't want to advertise an unimplemented method (even though `MutableCallSite` *without* `syncAll` doesn't seem like a useful construct). Were they right?

On the other hand, it seems really unlikely to be so glaringly missing its functionality. It has been in Java since Java 7, and apparently important projects like Nashorn and JRuby have made heavy use of `MutableCallSite` and `SwitchPoint`. I have not stumbled on any comments about them being broken because of it.

What's more, I understand that some implementations in the Java class library can look incomplete because parts of the magic are supplied by the JVM implementation. This seems like a prime example where that *could* be happening, but I haven't been able to find the details.

Does someone know the details? It would be good to know what the dependable behavior really is. The `syncAll` javadoc sounds very promising at first. Paraphrasing:

1. its effect is to force all future readers of each call site's target to accept the most recently stored value
2. it may (*may??*) block until all readers have (somehow) decached all previous versions
3. reader threads may observe previous versions of the target until the `syncAll` call returns. (*Does this mean they* may not *do so after the `syncAll` call returns? And if so, wouldn't that imply #2 is really something stronger than "may"?*)
4. it is "likely to be expensive" (as the trade-off for having `getTarget` be cheap; that's the magic part).

But later in the same javadoc, delving into JMM details, it says "*If* (some other thread) T executes a synchronization action A after the volatile write" ... *then* it must see the updated target.

That sounds a little ... less robust.

Is this all based on some JVM implementation knowledge that places an upper bound on how long that can take after the `syncAll` returns? If so, can that upper bound be stated?

If there really is nothing missing and the thing works as advertised, would it be worthwhile to remove the `// FIXME: NYI` in the source (and maybe replace it with an explanation of what really happens)?

For more: [earlier version of this question](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/mlvm-dev/2021-November/006906.html) posted on `mlvm-dev` list but didn't attract any answers.

Comment: I asked the same question a few months ago: http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2021-September/017422.html

Answer (score 0):

The comment from boneill, and the linked concurrency-interest mailing list response from Remi Forax, seem to contain the answer. The `MutableCallSite.syncAll` method really does not do what is advertised, but the behavior ends up being adequate because `MutableCallSite.setTarget` does *more* than is advertised. So in the scheme

```java
for ( i = 0; i < sites.length; ++ i )
  sites[i].setTarget(newTargets[i]);
MutableCallSite.syncAll(sites);
```

the necessary synchronization happens; it is just that most of the work happens before the `syncAll`. And likewise,

```java
SwitchPoint.invalidateAll(switchpoints);
```

(which is implemented as a loop just like the above, touching the `MutableCallSite` underlying each `SwitchPoint`) also the necessary work happens.

All is not perfect with this partially-implemented scheme, though: moving the heavy lifting from `syncAll` into `setTarget` looks like it sacrifices the advertised benefit of paying the `syncAll` cost just once after updating *n* call site targets. In this implementation, that cost (`mark_dependent_nmethods` and `deoptimize_all_marked` by handshaking with all threads) happens *n* times, but each time only handling the dependencies of one `CallSite`. Likewise for `SwitchPoint.invalidateAll` with an array of *n* `SwitchPoint`s.

I don't know why it's been left at this state of development since Java 7, but it looks like there is probably room for a nice performance boost if it ever gets implemented as originally documented.